# can't upload image to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is the first time i am trying to upload image to a database.i have the following piece of code to upload images to mysql database.But no images are being uploaded to the database.No error or warning has been given.Can't figure out what might be the problem.Any help will be appreciated.

php:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $name=$_FILES['files']['name'];
    if(!empty($name)){


        if(!file_exists($name)){
            $temp=$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

            //move_uploaded_file($temp,getcwd().'/uploads/'.$name);
            try{
                 $servername='localhost';
                 $username='root';
                 $password='';
                 $dbname='login';
                 $fp = fopen($temp, 'r');
                 $conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login',$username,$password);
                 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image_name, image) VALUES (?, ?)");

                 $stmt->bindParam(1, $_FILES['file']['name']);
                 $stmt->bindParam(2, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                 if($stmt->execute()){
                     echo 'its uploaded to database';
                 }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }else{

            echo 'file already exists';
        }
    }
    }else{
        echo 'select a file';
    }
```

HTML and js:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->

        <style>
            #mydiv{
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                width:80px;
                height:30px;
                background:crimson;
                color:white;
                text-align:center;
                padding:auto;
                border-radius:4px ;
                border:1px solid black;
                font-size:22px;
            }
            #files{
                   position: absolute;
                   top: 0;
                   right: 0;
                   margin: 0;
                   padding: 0;
                   font-size: 20px;
                   cursor: pointer;
                   opacity: 0;
                   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='file.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <div id='mydiv'>upload
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple />
      </div>
      <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
    </form>
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          console.log(theFile.type);
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.setAttribute('style','width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;');
          div.innerHTML = ['<img style="width:300px;height:300px;" class="thumb" src="',e.target.result,
                            '" title="',escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(div, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not want to store a `file pointer` to your database. You should read the file and then store what you have read from the file. Files dont read themselves by magic

Comment: study this carefully `$_FILES['file']`

Comment: Also you are allowing the upload of MULTIPLE FILES but you are making no attempt to process more than one file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly what is a file pointer actually?For a start i decided to go with one file :)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  php should give me some for that.How i am supposed to find such an error ?it's working now.Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well if you fixed it, then post your own answer, then this question will be of some use to other. That is afterall the point of this site!

Comment: it's called error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Checking at your PHP code, it is most probably the `$stmt->execute()` execution failed.

From PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php), you need to open your image in 'rb' mode:

`$fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');`

in order to insert it to the database

Comment: Not even close I am afraid. Opening a file is not enough, you have to read its contents

Comment: I believe the poster could at least carry out some debug by acknowledging he falls into the if else part of the `$stmt->execute()` statement; I have no experience in file upload, but I believe the carried PHP docs should be working...... probably PDO will do the reading in `execute()`